# Laravel 4: How to protect group routes admins and users?

Tags: laravel-4

Good day! Please tell me how to split the routes users and administrators? To authorize the user got to your home page and could move only to the right routes and the admin came on your web page and could see only their routes. 
My file routes.php

```
Route::get('/', array(
'as' => 'home',
'uses' => 'HomeController@home'
));




Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){

Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function(){

    Route::post('/account/change-password', array(
        'as' => 'account-change-password-post',
        'uses' => 'AccountController@postChangePassword'
    ));
});

Route::get('/account/change-password', array(
    'as' => 'account-change-password',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@getChangePassword'
));


Route::get('/user/{username}', array(
    'as' => 'profile-user',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
)); 

Route::get('/account/sign-out', array(
    'as' => 'account-sign-out',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@getSignOut'
));

});




Route::group(array('before' => 'admin'), function(){
Route::get('/dashboard', array(
    'as' => 'dashboard',
    'uses' => 'TiketsController@dashboard'
));

Route::get('/tiket-new', array(
    'as' => 'tiket-new',
    'uses' => 'TiketsController@tiketNew'
));

Route::get('/tiket-work', array(
    'as' => 'tiket-work',
    'uses' => 'TiketsController@tiketWork'
));

Route::get('/tiket-complete', array(
    'as' => 'tiket-complete',
    'uses' => 'TiketsController@tiketComplete'
));

Route::get('/tiket-arhive', array(
    'as' => 'tiket-arhive',
    'uses' => 'TiketsController@tiketArhive'
));
});


Route::group(array('before' => 'user'), function(){


Route::get('/user-dashboard', array(
    'as' => 'user-dashboard',
    'uses' => 'TiketsController@userDashboard'
));
});
```

My AccountController.php

```
public function postSignIn(){

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), 
        array(
            'email'          => 'required|email',
            'password'       => 'required'
    ));

    if($validator->fails()){

        return Redirect::route('account-sign-in')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
    } else {

        $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;



        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'email' => Input::get('email'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
            'active' => 1
        ), $remember);





        if($auth){
            if (Auth::user()->role==5) {

                return Redirect::intended('/dashboard');
            }
            if (Auth::user()->role==1) {

                return Redirect::intended('/user-dashboard');
            }


        } else {
            return Redirect::route('account-sign-in')
                ->with('global', 'Error');
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, when such routes admins and users can see the pages of each other. Please tell me as much detail as possible, how to distinguish between different groups of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
Route::filter('pattern: admin/*', 'auth')
```

this match patterns like

```
admin/cpanel
admin/dir/path/...
```

.
.
.

and

```
Route::filter('pattern: user/*', 'auth2')
```

Comment: Please tell me, of the filter to write to a file filter.php or routes.php?

Comment: this depend on how you want to authorize users, by default "auth" filter will check if user is guest or logged in (if guest redirect him to login page)

Comment: you can get current user info and check if he has privilege to visit admin page or not...